# How to change permission to the users on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, users, administration, user-management

How to change permission to the users to restrict their accessibility? I want to cannot see or cannot access the System Files, Devices and Network in home folder? I used ubuntu 12.04

Thanks,

Jerrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press windows key and type user in the search box which will list `Users and Groups`.

It will open the `Users Settings` interface. You can change permissions for individual users by clicking on the `user` and then click on `advanced settings`. In `Change Advanced User Settings` interface, select the `User Privileges` and choose your own restrictions for the user.

You will also need gnome-system-tools for GUI to work. If you have not installed it, type this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```